# What is struct in C?

Tags: python, c

I am new to C and this might be an elementary level question.

While reading over a C source file I found this:

```
struct globalArgs_t {
    int noIndex;
    char *langCode;
    const char *outFileName;
    FILE *outFile;
    int verbosity;  
    char **inputFiles;
    int numInputFiles;
} globalArgs;
```

For me, `globalArgs_t` seems like a function which for sure it isn't. What is this object? For what they are used? How do I use it?

I was looking for examples, I have a Python background.

Comment: This can easily be googled... 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)

Comment: A Bit harsh on the downvotes everyone... sure it can be googled easily, but its a good question for beginners.

Comment: Harsh perhaps but it shows zero effort to research. People who put effort into helping others expect a bit of effort on the part of the questioner. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: The StackOverflow says, `Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`. I say, **Not every question is asked for code**. At least the reason for closing the question is wrong.

Comment: @Kippie That is not beginner friendly. Not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to define offsets relative to a pointer in memory using names.

If you allocate enough memory for `globalArgs_t`, then `noIndex` will have the offset 0 in that memory area, `langCode` will have the offset 4 (offset of `noIndex` plus size of `noIndex`).

This way, you can easily access different values saved in memory without having to remember the exact offsets. It will also make your code more readable since you can give each offset a useful name plus the C compiler can do some type checks when you assign values.

Answer (score 2):

This statement does two things:

- It declares a new type `struct globalArgs_t` as a structure containing 7 fields
- It declares a new variable `globalArgs` of type `struct globalArgs_t`. Its fields can be accessed with the `.` operator, example: `globalArgs.verbosity = 2;`

Comment: It's especially useful in arrays. Imagine you have to represent a list of points by their (x, y) coordinates. Without structs, you'd be forced to use two int arrays and always manage them together; thanks to struct you can just use an array of structures `struct point { int x, y; }`.

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` is like a tuple. You can see it as a variable containing other variables.

```
struct globalArgs_t {
    int noIndex;
    char *langCode;
    const char *outFileName;
    FILE *outFile;
    int verbosity;  
    char **inputFiles;
    int numInputFiles;
} globalArgs;

// this function takes a pointer to a globalArgs_t struct
void myFunction(struct globalArgs_t *myStruct)
{
   // we're using the operator '->' to access to the elements 
   // of a struct, which is referenced by a pointer.
   printf("%i\n", myStruct->noIndex); 
}

int main()
{
    // We're using the operator '.' to access to the element of the structure
    globalArgs.noIndex = 5; 
    myFunction(&globalArgs); // A structure is a variable, so it has an address
    return 0;
}
```